# When trying to use \d+\s+/\d+\s+ in Python, it doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace text, contained a number, maybe some spaces, then "/", then maybe some spaces and a number, to ' number of number ', but no all methods work:

```
import re

text = '6/6, 7 / 40, 7/ 6, 8 /97'
print(re.sub(r'\d+/\d+', ' number of number ', text))  # works
print(re.sub(r'\d+\s+/\d+', ' number of number ', text)) # works
print(re.sub(r'\d+/\d+\s+', ' number of number ', text)) # not works
print(re.sub(r'\d+\s+/\d+\s+', ' number of number ', text)) # not works
```

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you mean to use something like `\d+\s*/\s*\d+`? See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsGh2U/1).

Comment: If you want to match a forward slash you have to use a backslash first.

Comment: Probably by some spaces you mean 'zero or more spaces'. Try `'[0-9]+\s*/\s*[0-9]+'`

Comment: @draycut `/` should not be escaped in string patterns, like in Python.

Comment: going by your description, is `r'\d+\s*/\s*\d+'` what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the trailing whitespace matching pattern right after `/`, change the `+` quantifiers after `\s` to `*`, and then you may use

```
import re
text = '6/6, 7 / 40, 7/ 6, 8 /97'
print(re.sub(r'\d+\s*/\s*\d+', ' number of number ', text))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hsGh2U/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cd%2B%5Cs*%2F%5Cs*%5Cd%2B):

[image]

**Pattern details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s*/\s*` - a `/` enclosed with 0 or more whitespaces
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

**NOTE**: In Python 3.x `re`, shorthand character classes are Unicode aware. To only match ASCII  digits, `[0-9]`, either use this character class, or use `re.ASCII` flag (it will also affect `\s` though):

```
re.sub(r'\d+\s*/\s*\d+', ' number of number ', text, flags=re.ASCII)
```